# How to regex for two words before and after specified string?

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using node.js and reading string for matching

```
 </em><em>
```

The same string used in regex

```
var regex=new RegEx('<\/em><em>',"g");
```

I want to get two words before and after the matched string.

```
E.g.,

   abc233 3344</em><em>abcd 3333
   3333abcd 3444</em><em>3333 dkdkd
```

Any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use split?

Comment: This is sample.  Actually the original string is from entire document.

Comment: Didn't get it. Splitting it with regex or splitting it with split - the resulting two parts will be equally complex.

Comment: Regex actually get example the same string(</em><em>).  Many matched string their in document.  I cannot able to predict the string combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regex :

```
/((?: |^)\w+){2}<\/em><em>(\w+(?: |$)){2}/gm
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/fY2qE3/1